# Force CSS Hexcode in HTML Output

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am trying to retrieve HTML-content from my (self-made) web based texteditor via a simple document.body.innerHTML retrieval which works fine.

For various reasons I want all css-color references (e.g. font-, border-,  background colors etc) to be in a hex-notation as opposed to a rgb() notation.

For example to convert all rgb values to hex of fontcolors I use a function rgb2hex():

```
var elems =     this.cont_doc.getElementsByTagName('*');
var len =       elems.length;
for(var n=0;n<len;n++)
{
    if(elems[n].style.getPropertyValue('color'))
    {
        var color = this.rgb2hex(elems[n].style.getPropertyValue('color'));//e.g rgb(255,38,0) becomes #ff2600 
        elems[n].style.setProperty('color',color);  
    }
}
```

However when I set colors in hex-format is always outputs the rgb-values in the end in for example `var output_string = this.cont_doc.body.innerHTML;` . Is there a way to preserve the hex-formatting or is there a regex solution i can apply in the final output_string ?

thank you
Patrick

Comment: What about named colors?

Comment: Colors for various elements are selected using a color-picker, so named ones cannot be used realisticly.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, Chrome forces all to `rgb` when requesting `innerHTML`. You can easily use a regexp on the HTML tough.

This is an example, just use it on your `innerHTML`.

```js
go.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const replaceRGB = (all, r, g, b) => [r, g, b].reduce((a, x) => a + (+x).toString(16).padStart(2, '0'), '#');
  output.value = input.value.replace(/rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)/g, replaceRGB);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
rgb(255, 50, 15);
</textarea>
<textarea id="output">
</textarea>
<button id="go">Process</button>
```

Comment: thanks, that does the job perfectly! To be sure do all browsers use lowercase for 'rgb' and no white space between rgb and the '(' sign?